# Breaking a semimartingale into non-semimartingale parts

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

I know that if $X_t$ is a semi-martingale then $X_t$ can be written as the sum of an martingale $M_t$ and a nice predictable process $A_t$.

I was wondering if the converse is false.  That is possible to have two processes $Y_t$ and $Z_t$, each not being semi-martingales but their sum
$$
Y_t+Z_t
$$
is a non-deterministic semi-martingale?  (My intuition says no, but maybe I'm overlooking something).

If not is it possible for the process
$$
Y_tZ_t
$$
to be a non-deterministic semi-martignale?

Comment: If $V_t$ is not a semimartingale, $V_t+(-V_t)$ and $e^{V_t}e^{-V_t}$ are semimartingales.

Comment: I modified the question a bit.